# Is it possible to access properties of an iOS system animation?

Tags: ios, animation, uikit

Is it possible to get the animation properties (speed and easing curve) for a built in iOS system animation? Specifically, the `UIStatusBarAnimationSlide` when you hide or show the status bar. Right now I'm just eyeballing it and have come up with a good match: .35 seconds using the default animation curve. This works fine, but Apple is liable to change an animation like this in a future iOS update and it would be nice to match it exactly and not rely on hard-coded values I came up with myself.

For what it's worth, here is the method my view controller is calling when I tap the view to hide the status bar and resize the view to fill the screen.

```
-(void)tappedView:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    // First, toggle the visibility of the status bar
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:![app isStatusBarHidden] withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    // Then scale this view controller's view, attempting to match the built-in
    // UIStatusBarAnimationSlide animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.35
            animations:^{
                self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
            }];
}
```

As an aside, I'm surprised I couldn't find a built in way to handle resizing a VC's view when the status bar is hidden. After all, if the status bar doubles its height when a call is in progress, the view resizes automatically. Tell me I'm missing something and there's a way to get the view to *grow* automatically, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a chuck of code I use in my app:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:
    (CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.355f animations:^{
        if(floating_point_values_are_equal(oldStatusBarFrame.size.height, 20.0f)) {
            for(UIViewController* VC in self.tabBarController.viewControllers) {
                UIView* view = VC.view;
                [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f)];
            }
        } else {
            for(UIViewController* VC in self.tabBarController.viewControllers) {
                UIView* view = VC.view;
                CGFloat ratio = (view.frame.size.height - 20) / view.frame.size.height;

                [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, ratio)];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

It basically scales the entire app depending on the new screen dimensions. It only works because the scale ratio is not a big change- doing this for the new iPhone screen would not look right.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't really answer the questions though. But I'm curious where you came up with the .355 seconds for the animation length. Seems pretty specific to just come up with via trial and error.

Comment: Oh. I thought you were just looking for a way of adjusting to a changing status bar! I actually came up with .355 with simply trial and error- it got to the point where I couldn't tell a difference, so I called it 'close enough.'

Comment: Ha... .35 works for me. I'm just hoping there's a better way to do this. I'm also hoping there's a better way to make a view controller's view automatically adjust to fill the space vacated by the status bar when it slides out of view. Seems weird if there isn't, being five years into iOS.